# Retrieve logs from Application Insights Using C# .NET Core function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I am building an Azure Function application to write and retrieve logs in ApplicationInsights. I can able to write logs using instrumentation key.

But I don't know how to retrieve the logs from Application Insights. I have googled and got some references to retrieve it through AD credentials but I don't have AD access. Without AD credentials (ClientId, SecretKey), how can I retrieve the logs data from Application Insights?

I need some guidance. Thanks

Comment: I believe you have excellent coding skills, the rest of you just need to send this http request in the code (same as I tested in postman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After My test, I found a good blog and verify it. If you don't have AD credentials (ClientId, SecretKey), you can use `AppInsightsId`, `AppInsightsAPIKey`. You can find it like below.

[image]

There will be some problems in the direct test of [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/get?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)（you may [found simillar issue here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159965/rest-api-with-azure-application-insights)）, please rest assured that the official should already know the existence of this problem. My sample Sample works fine. Please check the steps below.

#### Steps

1. Find the AppInsights Id and Key like the picture above.
2. Test in Postman.

   [image]
3. For more details, you can check the blog.

   [RETRIEVE APP INSIGHTS LOGS FROM A FUNCTION USING API REST](https://www.middleway.eu/retrieve-app-insights-logs-from-a-function-using-api-rest/)

Comment: Application Insights API Keys are deprecated and will be retired in March 2026, use Azure AD insteed.
[Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-azure-ad-api)